# Python Script To Periodically check website for result - Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to create a python script that will periodically refresh a website to extract data from it. I recently gave the SAT and so I want to automate the process of checking my score. But I am a complete beginner in Python and have no idea how to do it. The scores are delivered on Collegeboard's website (collegeboard.org) and they require login credentials. I'm not sure how easy it will be to login using a python script. Once you're logged in, the scores are displayed on this webpage - https://nsat.collegeboard.org/satweb/satHomeAction.action
Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so, how I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: it wouldn't be too difficult to code but I think it gonna be a bit harder because of the required login

Comment: If you have any code, show it. If you're a python beginner it might be better to learn python and then build the skills required to solve this problem. Its very unlikely someone would write a complete solution from the ground up for you as you're asking.